# Trying to get tomcat 7 working with eclipse 3.6.1

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to set up tomcat (v7.0.11) and eclipse (v3.6.1) so that I can debug JSP pages in eclipse. I'm going through these instructions:
http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html
and I'm on the step "Copy the ROOT (Default) Web App into Eclipse." which I did. However I still get a 404 error when I try to access http://localhost:8080 (after starting up tomcat through eclipse).

When I start up tomcat in eclipse I see a couple of warnings in the console but no errors:

```
Mar 30, 2011 8:10:23 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSPDataSource' did not find a matching property.
Mar 30, 2011 8:10:23 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSPEssbase2' did not find a matching property.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those warnings does actually not harm.

As to the problem of Tomcat's default homepage not being accessible when the server is started from inside Eclipse, first remove any deployed projects from Tomcat, then doubleclick the Tomcat server entry in *Servers* view to get its configuration. At the left column, under *Server Locations*, select *Use Tomcat installation*. This way Eclipse will take full control over Tomcat, so that you will be able to access the default Tomcat homepage with the Tomcat Manager at http://localhost:8080 when running from inside Eclipse. Note that you don't necessarily need to copy the ROOT in Eclipse workspace this way.

Optionally also check *Publish module contexts to separate XML files* under *Server options*. Otherwise Eclipse will modify the Tomcat's `server.xml` to its own taste, which may cause exactly those harmless XML validation warnings because Tomcat doesn't recognize Eclipse-specific XML attributes which Eclipse uses for own convenience to relate the Eclipse project to the deployed webapp.